# nunit where condition for categoriy not being set

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I have a bunch of testcases within my test-class:

```
[TestFixture]
class MyTestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1() { ... }

    [Test(Category = "MyCategory")]
    public void Test2() { ... }
}
```

What I want to achieve now is to run only the tests that have no category set using `nunit-console`. So in my example only `Test1` should run.

```
nunit3-console.exe MyAssembly.dll where "cat == null"
```

I also tried `"cat == ''"` with the same result.

However that won't give me *any* test. Of course I could use `"cat != 'MyCategory'"` in this contrived example, however as I have many categories I don't want to exlcude every one but instead chose just those **without** any category.

Comment: Did you try `cat !~ '.+'`?

Comment: @KlausGütter Wow, a regex for a simple null-check. It gets its job done, though. However I can´t imagine this to be the only way.

Comment: Indeed. But look at the `Match` method in the [source](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Filters/CategoryFilter.cs): a missing category will de evaluated as false, so a negation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the Match method in the [source](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Filters/CategoryFilter.cs) shows: a missing category will be evaluated as false.

So the condition *must* include a negation. As you already observed, `"cat != 'MyCategory'"` will include the tests without category, but will also include tests with a category other than 'MyCategory'.

To exclude all tests with *any* category, you can use the  `!~` operator (regex non-match), e.g.

```
where "cat !~ '.+'"
```